# Sublime Text Editor 2, Auto Indent Issue

Tags: format, sublimetext2

I am having issues with Sublime text editor removing my spacing, indenting all the way to the left.

For example:

```
%html{:lang => "en"}
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
  %body
```

upon save, becomes:

```
%html{:lang => "en"}
%head
%meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
%meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
%body
```

I can't find the fix online anywhere. I'm thinking I need to update my Sublime or change user preferences, but this seems to be a bug on my end.

Comment: What programming script/language are you using?  Is it just pure html or ??

Comment: @Leptonator, I'm using haml. When I use html, everything is fine. Seems to be the same case for my .yml files

Comment: I have just started with play with Sublime in my new LINUX build..  You should be able to register yml as a new file type.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend updating Sublime, because with Build 3083 my Sublime Text Editor recognizes .haml files as 'Ruby Haml'.

Second if HAML is not recognized in Sublime then try registering a syntax for all HAML files.

View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated to the newest version of sublime a few days ago and it solved my issues. Doesn't seem like many people encountered this issue, so I might have messed some core files up modifying settings.

Comment: Glad to help another Sublime fan!